# Angularjs GET request ends with 400(). Incorrect formulated inquiry?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have a webshop project in Spring, where I'm trying to handle adding itemst to Cart. 
The script fails on refreshCart method. It gives

> HTTP Status 400 - Incorrect request, check request data

**So here's my angualarjs script:**

```
var cartApp = angular.module('cartApp', []);

cartApp.controller('cartCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.refreshCart = function (cartId) {
        console.log("Cart id in refreshCart method controllers.js " + cartId);

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/rest/cart/' + cartId
        }).then(function successRefresh(singleCart) {
            $scope.cart = singleCart;
            console.log("Success, im inside");
            console.log(singleCart);
            console.log("After");
        }, function errorCallback(singleCart) {
            console.log("error in refreshCart");
        });

    };

    $scope.clearCart = function () {

        $http.delete('/rest/cart/' + $scope.cartId)
            .success($scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId));

    };

    $scope.initCartId = function (cartId) {

        $scope.cartId = cartId;
        $scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId);
    };


    $scope.addToCart = function (productId) {
        $http.put('/rest/cart/add/' + productId)
            .success(function (data) {

                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '/cart/getCartId'
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    $scope.cartId = response.data;
                    $scope.refreshCart($scope.cartId);

                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                });

                alert("Product has been succesfully added to cart!");
            });
    };
    $scope.removeFromCart = function (productId) {


        $http.put('/rest/cart/remove/' + productId)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.refreshCart($http.get('/rest/cart/get/cartId'));
            });
    };
});
```

**Spring REST controllers:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "rest/cart")
public class CartRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CartService cartService;

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;




    ////////////////////////////
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Cart read(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        System.out.println("I'm in read method in /rest/cart controller. CartId: " + cartId);
        for (Item item : cartService.read(cartId).getProducts().values()) {
            System.out.println(item.getProduct().getProductName());
        }
        return cartService.read(cartId);
    }

    /**
     * POST - Creates new Cart object
     * GET - Sends Cart object with id = cartId
     * PUT - Updates Cart object with id = cartId
     * DELETE - Delete Cart object with id  = cartId
     */

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    Cart create(@RequestBody Cart cart) {
        System.out.println("I'm in create method in /rest/cart controller. CartId: " + cart.getCartId());

        return cartService.create(cart);
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void update(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId, @RequestBody Cart cart) {
        System.out.println("I'm in update method in /rest/cart controller. CartId: " + cartId + " new cart : " + cart.getCartId());


        cartService.update(cart, cartId);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId) {
        System.out.println("I'm in delete method in /rest/cart controller. CartId: " + cartId);


        cartService.delete(cartId);
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/add/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void addItem(@PathVariable Integer productId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("I'm in addItem method in /rest/cart controller. productId: " + productId);

        String sessionId = request.getSession().getId();
        Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);
        if (cart == null) {
            cart = cartService.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }
        Product product = productService.findById(productId);
        if (product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        cart.addItemToCart(new Item(product));
        cartService.update(cart, sessionId);
        System.out.println("I'm in addItem method in /rest/cart controller. cart values: ");
        for (Item item : cart.getProducts().values()) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{productId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void removeItem(@PathVariable Integer productId, HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("I'm in removeItem method in /rest/cart controller. productId: " + productId);

        String sessionId = request.getSession().getId();
        Cart cart = cartService.read(sessionId);
        if (cart == null) {
            cart = cartService.create(new Cart(sessionId));
        }
        Product product = productService.findById(productId);
        if (product == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        cart.removeItem(new Item(product));
        cartService.update(cart, sessionId);
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason = "Incorrect request, check request data")
    public void handleClientErrors(Exception ex) {
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, reason = "Internal server error")
    public void handleServerErrors(Exception ex) {
    }

}
```

**Spring controllers:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/cart")
public class CartController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getCartId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public
    @ResponseBody
    String getCartId(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("I'm in getCartId method in /rest/cart controller. Session id: " + request.getSession(true).getId());

        return request.getSession().getId();
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/{cartId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCart(@PathVariable(value = "cartId") String cartId , ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("I'm in getCart method in /cart controller. CartId: " + cartId);

        model.addAttribute("cartId", cartId);
        return "cart";
    }

    @RequestMapping
    public String get(HttpServletRequest request){
        System.out.println("I'm in get method in /cart controller. Session id: " + request.getSession(true).getId() );


        return "redirect:/cart/" + request.getSession(true).getId();
    }



}
```

When I want to add new item to cart addToCart function is being invoked. According to the logs from controllers/dao/services everything is ok with this, but after that I want to refresh the cart. And there is my problem.

The request

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/rest/cart/' + cartId
        }).then(function successRefresh(singleCart) {
            $scope.cart = singleCart;
            console.log("Success, im inside");
            console.log(singleCart);
            console.log("After");
        }, function errorCallback(singleCart) {
            console.log("error in refreshCart");
        });
```

ends with

> HTTP Status 400 - Incorrect request, check request data

so I don't know what items are already in the cart, because I dont see any...

I can paste jsp files if needed.

Comment: not sure if this would help, but trying making cartId an int/long rather than a string

Comment: But where? In Cart model class? Or maybe just convert that string to int in angularjs script and then send request? On the other hand controller expects cartId to be String object.

Comment: In the controller, change from a string to an int and see if that helps/  If you're passing as an int rather than a string, then that will give you the 400 error

Comment: But te cartId that i pass looks like AE16AF7C24A1ABAFC67ECC6DB0175ABB so its definitely has to be aString.

Comment: you're not getting to System.out.println("I'm in read method in /rest/cart controller. CartId: " + cartId); correct?

Comment: Controller seems to be working. 

`I'm in read method in /rest/cart controller. CartId: 07D926A87AA758F45F4838738C94EE8E
I'm in read method in Cart service. cartId: 07D926A87AA758F45F4838738C94EE8E
I'm in read method in Cart DAO. cartId: 07D926A87AA758F45F4838738C94EE8E
Whey Protein 
I'm in read method in Cart service. cartId: 07D926A87AA758F45F4838738C94EE8E
I'm in read method in Cart DAO. cartId: 07D926A87AA758F45F4838738C94EE8E`


Cart DAO and Service are invoking twice because I am products in Cart and then I am returning the cart.

Comment: And when I go to http://localhost:8080/rest/cart it gives me 
`HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported
The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource
`

Comment: If you're getting to that read method, then where is the 400 error coming from? You usually won't even get to that stage is there is a 400 error.  Also, the 405 error makes sense, there is no controller endpoint for that request.